# How to immediately hide control bar on either JWPlayer or FlowPlayer while video loads

Tags: jwplayer, flowplayer

Using the code:

```
jwplayer('myPlayer').setup({ 
file: '/somefile.mp4',
'controlbar': 'none', 
'autostart': 'true',
'icons': 'false',
'width': '53px',
'height': '43px',
'repeat': 'always', 
'mute': 'true',
'stretching': 'fill', 
'controlbar.idlehide': 'true'
});
```

The video does exactly as it's supposed to while playing, however as it's starting and while it's "paused" between loop instances it's showing the time counter which breaks my design/intent.  Its supposed to just be a little looping thumbnail underneath of an image of a camera with a transparency to make it look like it's what the camera is shooting.

Isn't there some way to turn this off?

Comment: Are you using JW5 or JW6 here?

Comment: JW6, and i ended up having to create a custom skin for this solution... there seems to be no other way to accomplish it.

Comment: That is correct. You need to make a custom skin to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `player.setControls(false);`. If you want to hide controls after you hit "play" you could subscribe to `onPlay` event.

Answer (score 0):

Just Include the style on head section of page like

```
<style>
  .jwplayer.jw-state-idle .jw-controlbar {
    display: table;
  }
```